# Why isn't my python turned exe, not working?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

So I have this piece of code here:

```
import os
import sys

onlyfiles = [f for f in os.listdir(sys.path[0]) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(sys.path[0], f))]

while True:
    print(onlyfiles)
    x = input()
    if x == "y":
        continue
    else:
        break
```

I converted the script into a *.exe* file with pyinstaller. But when I try to run it, I assume it crashed?

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

your exe is crashing due to 'NotADirectory' error being thrown by the program.
As you are on windows, you can see this error.
Navigate to the path where you have created you exe and launch cmd.exe, and then execute your exe by issuing 'filename.exe' .

The 'NotADirectory' error is coming as now exe is frozen and system paths are changed as well, which include 'base_library.zip' . Certainly this is not a directory and hence exception is expected.